# Updating Visual Studio 2019 removed .NET Core 3.1 SDK

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

My operating system is **Windows 10 Pro**.

I had **Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.4.5 Version** installed. When I open **PowerShell** and run `dotnet --list-sdks` command, it list these 3 .NET Core SDKs:

> 1.0.0-preview2-003131 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
> 2.1.526 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
> 3.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

So the latest **.NET Core SDK** was `3.1.101`.

Now in Visual Studio 2019 Community I had to work with **.NET 5.0** projects which was not possible with current configuration. So I took these steps:

1. I install **.NET 5.0 SDK**.
2. I update Visual Studio 2019 Community to **Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.11.15 Version** via **Visual Studio Installer**.

Now in Visual Studio 2019 Community I can work with **.NET 5.0** projects. Great.

But I have lost .NET Core 3.1 SDK. When I open **PowerShell** and run `dotnet --list-sdks` command, it list these 3 .NET Core SDKs:

> 1.0.0-preview2-003131 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
> 2.1.526 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] 
> 5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

I was expecting that 4 .NET Core SDKs will be listed, as you can see `3.1.101` is missing.

Why `3.1.101` was deleted? I confirmed via **File Explorer** that `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk` folder does not have `3.1.101` folder anymore.

Comment: It is no longer available [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks) either, which is odd since 3.1 doesn't go eol until December 2022.  Still available [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1), but you have a reason to worry.